# Importing different SCSS files based on a state variable

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I have this state variable:

```
this.state = {
    theme: "light"
}
```

This state gets added to a divs class name so it becomes
`` <div class name=`app ${this.state.theme}`> ``

I also have three scss files: **App.scss**, **LightTheme.scss** and **DarkTheme.scss**. The app.scss has to import one of the theme scss files, because they have some color variables that make up the theme.

I tried to use scss's if statement but I discovered that scss can't be used to check if an element contains a particular class name or not.

Importing the theme files with JavaScript also doesn't work because the app.scss will have undefined variables.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can import the three files and add the `theme` class the very first div inside your `App.js`, something like this:

```js
function App() {

  return (
    <div className={`App theme-${this.state.theme}`}>
    ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

You would import all three `scss` files and then, inside, say **DarkTheme.scss** you can do as follows:

```
// ThemeDark.scss
.theme-dark {

  h1 {
    color: white;
  }

  .navigation {
     background-color: darkblue;
  }
}
```

```
// ThemeLight.scss
.theme-light {

  h1 {
    color: black;
  }

  .navigation {
     background-color: lightgray;
  }
}
```

Et cetera. In my case, I always use the light version as default always imported, but it might be a good division to do it as you suggest, and have a theme-neutral css file:

```
// App.scss
h1 {
   font-size: 2em;
}

.navigation {
   position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: All my styles are in **app.scss**. The theme files only contain color variables. I thought about doing it the way you suggested but I will add more scss files for different components later on, so I'd end up writing the colors over and over again.

Comment: Yes, there is indeed a lot of repetition. You could go for CSS variables or [SASS-themed](https://medium.com/@dmitriy.borodiy/easy-color-theming-with-scss-bc38fd5734d1), the last articles seems to be an interesting approach, as you would only need to define one file. In my case, I usually define a colors.scss file, so that I can do $gray_dark, or $gray_50, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you import **`App.scss`** in to `LightTheme.scss` and also in to `DarkTheme.scss` as the first line?

```
@import "../../App.scss";  /*add path to App.scss*/
```

Then you can call either `LightTheme.scss` or `DarkTheme.scss` which should work as you're expecting.

---

### EDIT

*"All my styles are in app.scss. The theme files only contain color variables."*

1. Create a new file **light-theme.scss**
2. Add these 2 line in it.

   ```
   @import "../../LightTheme.scss";  /*variables*/
   @import "../../App.scss";  /*styles*/
   ```
3. Create another new file **dark-theme.scss**
4. Add these 2 line in it.

   ```
   @import "../../DarkTheme.scss";  /*variables*/
   @import "../../App.scss";  /*styles*/
   ```

Now just call **light-theme.scss** or **dark-theme.scss** as you planned.

Comment: I tried to do that, but the import statement is outside of the ```class App extends Component {...}``` so it doesn't know the ```theme``` state.

Comment: I just added another approach to help you solve this issue. Check the edit section.